# R Calculate the two way margins in an 5 dimesional array

Tags: arrays, r, aggregate

I have a 5 dimensional array and I want to calculate all the 2-way marginal sums in the array. For an illustrative example, with a 3 dimensional array:

`a <- array(1:24,c(2,3,4))`

I would like to calculate the 2-way marginals with dimensions:

x[2,3]; y[2,4]; and z[3,4]

so x[2,3] would look like

```
       [,1]    [,2]    [,3]
[1,]     40      48      56
[2,]     44      52      60
```

Obviously, there will be 10 such 2-way marginal sums in a 5 dimensional  array.

Thanks

Comment: Not sure, but are you looking for `combn(length(dim(a)), 2, function(d) rowSums(aperm(a, c(d, seq_along(dim(a))[-d])), dims = 2L), simplify = FALSE)`?

Comment: Thanks alexis. That looks to do the job. I'll need to spend a few minutes working out why!